# Can I upload database backup made through cPanel into phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have been using mybb forum software. As, I use shared hosting so they had provided me cPanel. Through it I had make a backup which is a .gzip file.

Now, my query here is that I want to upload it to another server to do some experiments with my forum. Can I upload the file through phpmyadmin? As my server has no cPanel installed. Will it work?

Comment: does this gzip contain a .sql file?

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked and yes, the gzipped file is a standard mysql dump, so you can import it from PhpMyAdmin (given that the MySQL versions are compatible, of course).

The backup doesn't contain the `CREATE SCHEMA` statement, so you have to create the db first, and then import the backup into it.

Comment: I asked it because will it work in a new mybb installation or not.